# SQL result as a list

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to build a sql that will return the customers for a specific invoice as a list.

To better explain myself I've attach a diagram of what I'm trying to accomplish.

[image]

AS you can see from the SQL Result I would like the SQL to show the customers as a list for each invoices.number

How would I accomplish the SQL (for SQL SERVER)?

Comment: You have a pretty good database design going into this, but it puzzles me why you want to have a result set with comma-separated values.  This is almost never a good idea.

Comment: @Shark, that seems like a pretty standard requirement.  Why do you say it's a bad idea?  I would agree that it's a bad idea if he were storing that information in his database, but if he needs to select his data in that format based on business requirements what does it hurt?

Comment: Yes it's a business requirement for presentation purpose.

Comment: @Yannick, yeah that's a fairly common request when presenting data.  I can't think of any reason that it would not be a good idea.

Comment: If this is for presentation, general design principles are that you should process the normalised results in your client, and process the strings for presentation in your presentation layer...

Comment: Interesting, I've never heard that.  Can you post any documentation regarding this?  I'd like to read up on it if I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
declare @Invoices table(ID int, Number varchar(10))
declare @Customers table(ID int, Name varchar(20))
declare @InvoiceCustomers table(InvoiceID int, CustomerID int)

insert into @Invoices values (1, 'INV01')
insert into @Customers values (1, 'NAME1'),(2, 'NAME2'),(3, 'NAME3')
insert into @InvoiceCustomers values (1, 1),(1, 2),(1, 3)

select I.Number as InvoicesNumber,
       stuff((select ', '+C.Name
              from @Customers as C
                inner join @InvoiceCustomers as IC
                  on C.ID = IC.CustomerID
              where IC.InvoiceID = I.ID
              for xml path(''), type).value('.', 'varchar(max)'), 1, 2, '') as CustomersName
from @Invoices as I
```